# Time Complexity of printing an Array of String

Tags: java, c++, arrays, string, algorithm

Given the Pseudocode -

```
function PrintColours(): 
    colours = { "Red", "Green", "Blue", "Grey" } 
    
    foreach colour in colours: 
        print(colour)
```

What should be the Overall Time Complexity of the Code. Is it O(n) or O(n^2) ?

Does it take longer time to print a longer string, or is it the same for all (as is the case in integers) ?

Comment: If strings have a fixed limit on their length, it's `O(n)` no matter how big is that max length. If there is no such max, it's `O(k)` where `k` is the total number of characters in all strings.

Comment: @SergeyKalinichenko so does that make the complexity of the algorithm quadratic ?
Assuming all strings are equal in size `m` as the size of every string, with `n` being the size of the array.
Overall Complexity would be O(n*m) ~ O(n^2)

Comment: If `m` is constant, `O(m*n)` is `O(n)` regardless of the value of `m` (10, 100, or 1,000,000, it does not matter), because we ignore all constants during the big-O analysis.

Comment: I have currently assumed "m" to be the size of all strings in the array.
lets say the size of the string at index `i` is `mi`.
Overall Complexity would be `O(m0 + m1 + m2 + m3 +... mn-1)`.

Would this be considered linear or quadratic ?

Comment: In this case `m` is a number in its own rights, because by the time you finish computing it,  `n` is out of the picture, so the complexity is linear in `m`, i.e. `O(m)`.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the time complexity would be O(n) because strings have a max length so O(k*n) (k being the max string length) works out to be O(n).

But to answer your question, yes, longer strings take longer to print.

Answer (score 0):

O(k*n) is the correct time complexity because it has to iterate only the numbers of data it has. O(n^2) usually applies if you are having a loop inside a loop or an array inside an array or a multidimensional array.

Now talking about strings it is a kinda multidimensional array that consists of a character array and an array of those character arrays. But you see the size of the array can differ so it cant be O(n^2). Instead, we can use O(k*n) where k refers to the max_length of string you have.

Now you can clearly see how much string takes time to execute vs how much int takes time to execute.